# What does the descriptor's default value mean in Object.defineProperty()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), when using `Object.defineProperty()`, its third argument is a descriptor with some optional keys, such as

> `configurable`
>   true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.
>   **Defaults to false.**
>
> `enumerable`
>   true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.
>   **Defaults to false.**

...

I'd like to ask what does the **defaults to false** above mean?

I think it means that if I don't specify that key's value, it will be set to the default value, which is `false`, but when I try it in Chrome, it turns out to be as follows:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'a')
> {value: "c", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
Object.defineProperty(o, 'a', {'enumerable': false})
> {a: "c"}
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'a')
> {value: "c", writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```

Apparently my descriptor missed the key `configurable`, but this attribute was not set to `false`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That’s because `configurable` is already set, since the property exists.Try it with a non-existing property.

Comment: @FelixKling here all legal keys' value will be initiated (as `ture`) when a property is created, thus there aren't any non-existing keys I think. And what I'd like to know is when these **default value** are used.

Comment: @FelixKling it was my misunderstanding that these keys are always existing. You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the same MDN article:

> When the property already exists, Object.defineProperty() attempts to modify the property according to the values in the descriptor and the object's current configuration.

Since `o.a` already exists, `Object.defineProperty()` modifies the property with provided descriptor instead of defining it from scratch. In this case it only overwrites the keys you provide.

You can see the defaults in action by defining a new property.

```
var o = {}
> undefined
Object.defineProperty(o, 'a', {})
> {a: undefined}
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'a')
> {value: undefined, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

Comment: Thanks, this perfectly answers my question!